# how to configure spring boot with spring security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Im trying to start a spring boot application by integrate spring security, following an example.
My problem is how to configure correctly my application, 
For now, I success login then when I try to acces to any url I had always error 403! And I didn't understand really the problem.
This is my securtyConfig:

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf();;
}
```

MvcConfig:

```
 @Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/403").setViewName("403");
}
```

My Login page:

```
<form action="/home" method="post" class="form-signin">
            <p class="text-muted text-center btn-block btn btn-primary btn-rect">
                Enter your username and password
            </p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  name="username" class="form-control" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" />
            <button class="btn text-muted text-center btn-danger" type="submit">Sign in</button>

                        <c:if test="${param.error ne null}">
            <div class="alert-danger">Invalid username and password.</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout ne null}">
            <div class="alert-normal">You have been logged out.</div>
        </c:if>
           <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" /> 
        </form>
```

Now after login, when I try to access to any url I had error 403! 
Example:

```
 <form action="/alo" method = "POST">
                        <input type="text" name="test"/>
                        <input type="submit"/>
                        </form>
```

The controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/alo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dashboard() {
    System.err.println("PRIN: ");
    return "/";
}
```

The controller is never been invocat!!

Anyone Has an idea please?

Comment: Is it fair to assume that you've gone through this first?  https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: yes sure I read it

Comment: Did you go through it?  Does their work?  (Yes.)

Comment: yes ofcourse, I try their example and it work.. in My case, I use JDBC authentication, and JSP instead of thymleaf

Comment: You are using csfr, but aren't including the token, so you will not have access.

Comment: No, Im login! and I access to home page! the verification of users is correct...